# How to get the values of Columns in Java SWT Table

Tags: java, swt

I would like to ask on how to get the corresponding values from each column from SWT table. I'm having a hard time to get this one, I hope you can help me this time. So my problem is I have columns and I want to get the values of this columns. Attached here is the screenshot of the sample table on my program

[image]

In this case, I want to get the values from Column1 - Column6 (1250, 2305, 1120,2450,2312,2134) and get the total of it and store it on a 
Textbox. I still have a table where there is a checkbox that when you checked it will automatically display the values as shown. I tried to get the values but it seems its not working with the code that I have.

```
TotalItem= 0L;
    for (x= 0; x < tblPrice.length; x++) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < tblPrice[x].getColumnCount(); y++){ //columns
                if (tblItems[x].getItem(x).getChecked()) {
                    TotalItem = TotalItem+ Long.parseLong(tblPrice[x].getItem(y).getText());
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Can you post what types are your column and table? What packages are you importing and what exactly tool are you using.

Comment: it would be easier if you used arraylists.  1) loop your csv via into your swing table,  (2) save each column within a separate arraylist. (3) use get methods to call each separately or preform whatever calculations you want to do with them.

Comment: What is `tlbPrice`, what is `tlbItems`? Show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell which bit you're struggling with, but I'm going to assume that you're not getting the value back from the table that you want.

You're calling `TableItem#getText()`, which will give you the value of the first column in that row.
If you want to get the text at a specific column, you have to call [`TableItem#getText(int)`](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TableItem.html#getText-int-) with the corresponding table column index.

The following example should illustrate this. It shows a table with three columns and when you click on a cell, it prints the value of that cell.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    int cols = 3;
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + c);
    }

    int rows = 10;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            item.setText(c, r + " " + c);
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        table.getColumn(c).pack();

    table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, e -> {
        Point pt = new Point(e.x, e.y);
        TableItem item = table.getItem(pt);

        if (item != null)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < table.getColumnCount(); c++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(c);
                if (rect.contains(pt))
                {
                    System.out.println(item.getText(c));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```